# how to purge journal queue in c#?

Tags: c#, msmq, purge, journal

i am getting the purge to work on a queue but not on its journal
any idea why?
MessageQueue oque1 = new MessageQueue(Qname);
oque1.UseJournalQueue = true;
oque1.Purge();

Answer (score 1):

The journal is a different queue. You have to refer it explicitly to purge it.